# Search product URL as catalog/view/id/213 Magento 2

Tags: catalogsearch, magento-2.1.8, product-urls

I have disabled **Use Categories Path for Product URLs**, so the product URL

Example: www.example.com/product-url

Which is fine.

But I have added some products which have **visibility as search** only.

When I am searching these products then search results are fine. But the search products URL is not same as above example.

URL is as www.example.com/catalog/view/id/213.

If I change visibility as **catalog** or **catalog,search** then the URL with url-key as exam

How can I change URL as www.example.com/product-url ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a redirect 301 to correct product url, in **.htaccess** or in backend in Marketing > SEO & SEARCH > Url rewrites

**EDIT**

Create an url rewrite for product in backend with target url www.example.com/product-url

Comment: If I hit the url-key with base url it is showing 404 error.

Comment: Is it possible without doing this?

Comment: Did you find any solution for this im facing the same issue but no result